# Fluent interface and polymorphism for building a scene with shapes

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, polymorphism, fluent-interface

I would like to improve the interfaces of some polymorphic classes going from positional to named parameters and I came up with the fluent interface.

The following is the most clean, compact and compilable (-std=c++11 required) example that I have been able to come up with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Figure {
  string _name;
  Figure * name(const string & str) { _name=str; return this; }
  virtual double area() const=0;
};

struct Circle: Figure {
  double _radius;
  Circle * radius(double r) { _radius=r; return this;}
  double area() const override {return M_PI*_radius*_radius;}
};

struct Square: Figure {
  double _side;
  Square * side(double s) { _side=s; return this;}
  double area() const override {return _side*_side;}
};

struct Scene {
  vector<Figure*> v;
  ~Scene() { for (auto & f : v) delete f; }
  Scene & add(Figure * f) {v.push_back(f); return *this;}
  double total_area() const {
    double total=0;
    for (auto f : v) total += f->area();
    return total;
  }
};

int main() {
  Scene scene;
  scene.add((new Circle)->radius(1.)->name("c1"))
       .add((new Square)->  side(1.)->name("s1"));
  cout << "Total area: " << scene.total_area() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have a couple of issues with this:

1. That is an ugly place to have a `new` operator, could it be avoided somehow?
2. After having called the method `name("name")` the type is lost so there is still an ordering to respect: `add((new Square)->name("s1")->side(1.))` will not compile. You should imagine to have many levels of inheritance and lots of parameters to be setted!

How would you address these issues and improve the code? C++1y is allowed and preferred to Boost?

---

For *further improvements* see the related question: [Variadic templates and pointers to member functions to achieve a named-parameters interface in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42748/variadic-templates-and-pointers-to-member-functions-to-achieve-a-named-parameter)

Comment: as a quick aside: you can solve the type problem with a template, e.g. `template <T> struct Figure { T name(...) ...}`, then `struct Square: Figure<Square*>`. Not sure if that's the exact syntax, but the general idea should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Another thing to consider in your current design:

```
~Scene() { for (auto & f : v) delete f; }
```

You are calling the destructor of the base here, not the derived classes' destructors. Remember to make a virtual destructor in your class to solve this problem.

Comment: Of course, I just did't want to overload the example making the question less clear, so please stick to the questions!

Comment: Cheers. You just emphasized that your example was working and compilable, so i thought i would chip in.. :)

Comment: @DarioP - as per the [help/on-topic] people can review any aspect of your code... 'please stick to the questions!' is a request, not a demand. Shaggi, welcome to code-review, you just passed the first-answer review ;-)

Comment: In the framework of the example what's the point of the virtual destructor? It does absolutely nothing, however I accept the help center policy.

Comment: @rolfl why thanks! i guess i'm used to stackoverflow's mentality
-dariop sorry for going 'offtopic', that wasn't my intention. however to answer your question (in your comment), since you are deleting a derived class through a base class pointer without a virtual destructor, you're actually invoking undefined behaviour afaik.

Comment: @Shaggi I'm just using the destructor of the base class, which is totally fine in this case. The example compiles just fine on gcc and does not have any leak, but the most important aspect is it does what it was written for: illustrate the weak points I have in my interface design.

Comment: But it _is not_ totally fine. Yes it works, but you're still invoking undefined behaviour (which may or may not immediately show itself)

Comment: By running this program I will have my hdd formatted, but not now, in ten years! Ok, I can live with this fantasy. Nobody is saying is not correct, but it is simply not the point. That's all.

Comment: Nice answer!  Keep up the good work!

Comment: Since this has become the most upvoted answer, I'm accepting this as a protest against a community behaviour that I find totally crazy. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 7):

> After having called the method name("name") the type is lost so there is still an ordering to be respected: add((new Square)->name("s1")->side(1.)) will not compile.

You could do that using a template as follows:

```
template<typename TSelf>
struct Figure {
  string _name;
  TSelf* name(const string & str)
  {
    _name=str;
    return (TSelf*)this; // could be a dynamic or static cast
  }
  virtual double area() const=0;
};

struct Circle: Figure<Circle> {
  ... etc ...
};
```

An alternative would be a method in the subclass, which hides the method in the superclass:

```
struct Circle: Figure {
  Circle* name(const string & str) { Figure::name(str); return this; }
  ... etc ...
};
```

Comment: Static polymorphism would require me a lot of refactoring, but your second alternative is cool: it allows me to stress all the parameters that are important to an object, just looking at its header! Thank you, +1

Answer (score 7):

> I have a couple of issues with this:
>
> 1. That is an ugly place to have a new operator, could it be avoided somehow?
> 2. After having called the method name("name") the type is lost so there is still an ordering to respect: add((new Square)->name("s1")->side(1.)) will not compile.
>
> You should imagine to have many levels of inheritance and lots of parameters to be setted!

`1.` Yes. You can use a solution based on passing a std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr (unique_ptr should be prefered if you are passing ownership, like in your example).

**Second edit**:

Alternately, you could try implementing this:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Figure>> v;

template<typename T, typename ...Args>
Shape& add(Arg... args)
{
    // I think this is correct;
    // but don't have compiler nearby
    v.emplace_back(std::unique_ptr<Figure>{new T{std::forward<Args>(args)...}});
}
```

client code:

```
Shape s;
s.add<Circle>("c1", 10); // assumes constructor shown at point below (2)
```

**End second edit**.

`2.` You are writing client code assuming that your Figure class hierarchy     supports polymorphic behavior (i.e. `(new Circle)->name("c1")->radius(1.)` assumes that the return type of `name()` will support a `radius` function).

This implies you should write the `Figure` base class to support invalid operations on compilation:

```
struct Figure {
    string _name;
    Figure * name(const string & str) { _name=str; return this; }
    virtual double area() const=0;
    virtual Figure * radius(double r) { throw std::logic_error("invalid op."); }
    virtual Figure * side(double s) { throw std::logic_error("invalid op."); }
    // any other operations here
};
```

**Edit**: The correct solution (since we are all creative people, "correct" is actually debatable) would be to avoid call chains for constructing your objects completely:

old code:

```
Scene scene;
scene.add((new Circle)->radius(1.)->name("c1"))
     .add((new Square)->  side(1.)->name("s1"));
```

new code:

```
struct Circle: Figure {
    double _radius;
    Circle(std::string name, double radius = 0.)
        : Figure{std::move(name)}, _radius{radius} {}
    // ... 
};

struct Square: Figure {
    double _side;
    Square(std::string name, double side = 0.)
        : Figure{std::move(name)}, _side{side} {}
    // ... 
};

Scene scene;
scene.add(new Circle{"c1", 1.});
scene.add(new Square{"s1", 1.});
```

**End edit**.

Comment: Your edit is exactly what I have now and what I want to improve since those cctors contains way to many parameters! By the way, why you are using std::move instead of the good old const reference?

Comment: @DarioP, It is a design principle that states you should pass completely constructed objects into your constructors. If the object has it's own copy of the value (i.e. Figure::_name is not a const reference) I prefer to create the value in the constructor. This has the advantage of enabling all std::string constructors optimally, or close (consider: `Circle c{std::string{b, e}};` where b and e are iterators: to implement optimally with `const&`, you would need a new constructor (`Circle(std::string&&)`). Passing std::string by value enables use of `std::string(std::string&&)`.

Comment: In the end I guess it's a matter of style/consistence and coding conventions for your project.

Comment: @DarioP, to reduce the number of parameters, consider passing in a collection of values (`Circle c{"c1", defaults};` where defaults looks like `struct X { const double default_radius = 1; const double default_width = .5; /* etc. */} const defaults;`. Then, it's a single parameter :).

Comment: I believe that your `new T{std::forward<Args>(args)}` lacks an ellipsis after `arg` :)

Comment: @Morwenn, Thanks, I have edited the code.

Answer (score 6):

I disagree with the fundamental motivation here. Fluent interfaces are fine for builder objects, but constructing a half-baked class and initializing its fields with chained setters just feels wrong. The constructor should be enough to initialize the object.

As for the pointer, consider using value semantics polymorphic objects through type erasure, as demonstrated by Sean Parent here:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_BpMYeUFXv8

The slides can be found here:

https://github.com/boostcon/cppnow_presentations_2012

**Edit:** Since that presentation is quite long, a short summary: the idea is to have types that act polymorphic but have value semantics. In a way they act like custom smart pointers, but they completely hide their pointer nature. `std::function<>` is an example of such a type.

Here's a very simple example of what that might look like.

```
class Figure {
private:
  class Interface {
  public:
    virtual ~Interface() {}
    virtual Interface* copy() const = 0;
    virtual std::string name() const = 0;
    virtual double area() const = 0;
  };
  template <typename T>
  class Implementation : public Interface {
    T t;
  public:
    Implementation(const T& t) : t(t) {}
    Implementation(T&& t) : t(std::move(t)) {}
    Interface* copy() const override { return new Implementation(*this); }
    std::string name() const override { return t.name(); }
    double area() const override { return t.area(); }
  };
  std::unique_ptr<Interface> value;

public:
  template <typename T>
  Figure(T&& t) : value(new Implementation(std::forward<T>(t))) {}

  Figure(const Figure& o) : value(o.value->copy()) {}
  Figure& operator =(const Figure& o) { value.reset(o.value->copy()); }
  ~Figure() = default;

  double area() const { return value->area(); }
};

class Circle { // no inheritance
  std::string myname;
  double myradius;

public:
  Circle(const std::string& name, double radius)
      : myname(name), myradius(radius) {}
  std::string name() const { return myname; }
  double area() const { return myradius * myradius * M_PI; }
};

class Scene {
  std::vector<Figure> v; // no pointers

  template <typename T>
  Scene& add(T&& f) { v.push_back(std::forward<T>(f)); return *this; }
  double total_area() const {
    return boost::range::accumulate(
        v | boost::adapters::transformed(
                [](const Figure& f) { return f.area(); }));
  }
};
```

Comment: I agree with you: even default constructors should always return fully constructed objects, eventually with a set of default parameters. That's fine, I never thought about doing differently. Is there a code snippet that illustrate the concept explained in about a couple of hours presentation?

Answer (score 6):

What you've written isn't really a "named parameter" API; it's more of a "getter/setter" API. Here's what it would look like in idiomatic C++11 — basically, changing all your `new/delete` heap traffic into plain old objects and using `setName()` for your mutator instead of just `name()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Figure {
    std::string m_name;
    Figure& setName(const std::string& str) { m_name = str; return *this; }
    virtual double getArea() const = 0;
};

struct Circle : public Figure {
    double m_radius;
    Circle& setRadius(double r) { m_radius = r; return *this; }
    Circle& setName(const std::string& str) { Figure::setName(str); return *this; }
    double getArea() const { return M_PI * m_radius * m_radius; }
};

struct Square : public Figure {
    double m_side;
    Square& setSide(double s) { m_side = s; return *this; }
    Square& setName(const std::string& str) { Figure::setName(str); return *this; }
    double getArea() const { return m_side * m_side; }
};

struct Scene {
    // Unfortunately, the naive implementation of polymorphism
    // requires heap traffic. We can fix this, but for now let's
    // leave it using the heap.
    //
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Figure>> v;

    // Move an arbitrary Figure into the scene.
    template<typename FigureSubclass>
    Scene& add(FigureSubclass &&f) {
        using FSC = typename std::remove_reference<FigureSubclass>::type;
        std::unique_ptr<Figure> newFig(new FSC(std::forward<FigureSubclass>(f)));
        v.emplace_back(std::move(newFig));
        return *this;
    }

    double getTotalArea() const {
        double total=0;
        for (const auto& f : v) total += f->getArea();
        return total;
    }
};

int main() {
    Scene scene;
    scene.add(Circle().setRadius(1).setName("c1"))
         .add(Square().setSide(1).setName("s1"));
    std::cout << "Total area: " << scene.getTotalArea() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For "non-naive" implementations of polymorphism (and/or heterogeneous containers), see [Sean Parent's talk at GoingNative](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil) or other StackExchange questions such as [Ad hoc polymorphism and heterogeneous containers with value semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18856824/ad-hoc-polymorphism-and-heterogeneous-containers-with-value-semantics) (a great grab-bag of keywords for your further Google-searching, btw).

On the *other* other hand, when I hear "named parameters", I think of an API that's more like

```
Scene.add(Circle("radius", 1.0))
     .add(Square("side", 1.0));
```

which is a whole new bag of problems, but doesn't have anything to do with polymorphism/heterogeneity.

Comment: I do not see the point of having `set` in front of every methods, but all the rest looks very nice! I also appreciate a lot the fact of using `.` instead of `->`.

Answer (score 3):

> That is an ugly place to have a new operator, could it be avoided somehow?

The accepted answer to [About the usage of new and delete, and Stroustrup's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20848444/49942) suggests you use [`std::make_shared`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) instead.